# My conjecture $\int_{0}^{1}{x^n-1 \over \ln(x)}dx=\ln(n+1)$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{1}{x^n-1 \over \ln(x)}dx=\ln(n+1)$$

Let deal with case $n=1$

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}{x-1 \over \ln(x)}dx=\ln(2)$$

$u=\ln(x)$ $\rightarrow du=\frac{1}{x}dx$

$x \rightarrow 1 ,u=0$

$x \rightarrow 0, u=-\infty$

$$I=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2u}-e^u}{u}du$$

Apply integration by parts

$$I=\left.(e^{2u}-e^u)\ln(u)\right|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}(2e^{2u}-e^u)\ln(u)du$$

Letting

$$J=\int_{0}^{\infty}(2e^{2u}-e^u)\ln(u)du$$

Applying by parts again

$$J=\left.(2e^{2u}-e^u)\ln(u)\right|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}(2e^{2u}-e^u)\frac{1}{u}du$$

Anyway I skip the simplification and get to the result

$$2I=\left.e^{2u}\ln(u)\right|_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2u}}{u}du$$

That doesn't looked correct!

Integration by parts and substitution seem to failed here for me, so what is another method to evaluate this integral?

Another attempt using $x^n-1=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-1)x^k$

$$\int_{0}^{1}{x^n-1 \over \ln(x)}dx=\ln(n+1)$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{1}{(x-1)x^k \over \ln(x)}dx=\ln(n+1)$$

This is still involving Integration by parts, I am very sure is going to lengthy so I am stopping here for help. Please lend me a hand, thank you.

Here is a link to [Frullani's formula](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.2940.pdf)

Comment: This can't  be duplicate, because here I asked specific on the general of the formula. I am not asking for specific $x^7$

Comment: If you actually **read** the answers posted in that question, you will find the general solution.

Comment: I haven't read so, ok it is duplicate thank you.

Comment: Further duplicates to prove my point:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263568/how-to-calculate-the-integral-i-int-limits-01-fracxn-1-lnx-mathrm-d?lq=1  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254548/an-integration-question-to-be-solved-without-using-differentiation-under-the-int  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778278/hints-on-calculating-the-integral-int-01-fracx19-1-ln-x-dx?lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your conjecture is a trivial consequence of [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) after the substitution $x=e^{-z}$.

Comment: Wasting my time on a trivial formula, thank you.

Comment: @Chinacat. You are not wasting your time, be sure ! Go on.

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to prove this (while also generalising your statement to any real number) is by using the technique of differentiating under the integral sign. Let $$f(\alpha)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^\alpha -1}{\log x} dx.$$ By differentiation under the integral we see that $$f'(\alpha)=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\left(\frac{x^\alpha -1}{\log x}\right)dx=\int_0^1 x^\alpha dx=\frac{1}{1+\alpha}$$ hence $$f(\alpha)=\int \frac{d\alpha}{1+\alpha}=\log(1+\alpha)+C.$$ But we notice from the definition that $f(0)=0$ so it follows that $C=0$ which completes the proof.

Comment: Feynmann comes to the rescue.  +1

Comment: @user1892304 can you show me how you get from $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}{x^{\alpha}-1 \over \log(x)}$ to $x^{\alpha}$

Comment: I may need to know to solve another problem similar to this one

Comment: @Chinacat In this step we are taking the partial derivative with respect to $\alpha$ so we consider $x$ as a constant. Here $-1/ \log x$ is a constant so it goes away, and the derivative of $x^\alpha$ w.r.t. $\alpha$ is $x^\alpha \log x$ so the $\log x$'s cancel out leaving just $x^\alpha$.